# HTML in selenium firefox webdriver not loading

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, headless, geckodriver

I am trying to scrape a website using `Selenium Firefox` (headless) driver in `python`.

I read all the anchors in the webpage and go through them all one by one. But I want for the browser to wait for the `Ajax` calls on the page to be over before moving to another page.

My code is the following:

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  complete

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

url = "http://localhost:3000/"

# Using Selenium's webdriver to open the page
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=caps,firefox_options=options)
driver.get(url)
urls = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a")))

links = []

for url in urls:
    links.append(url.get_attribute("href"))

for link in links:
    print 'navigating to: ' + link
    driver.get(link)
    body = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "p")))
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,1000);")
    print(body)    
    driver.back()

driver.quit()
```

the line `print(body)` was added for testing purposes. and it returned uncomprehensible text , instead of the actual HTML of the page. Heres a part of the printed text :

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="e7dfa6b2-1ddf-438d-b562-1e2ac8416e07")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="6fe1ffb0-17a8-4b64-9166-691478a0bbd4")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="1f510a00-a587-4ae8-9ecf-dd4c90081a5a")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="c1bfb1cd-5ccf-42b6-ad4c-c1a70486cc98")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="be44db09-3948-48f1-8505-937db509a157")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="68f3c9f2-80b0-493e-a47f-ad69caceaa06")>,
```

What is causing this?

Everything (content related) in the pages i'm scraping is static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your current code trial the output you are seeing is pretty much justified.

### presence_of_all_elements_located(locator)

[presence_of_all_elements_located()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located) is the expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page. A [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) is used to find the elements and returns the `List` of *WebElements* once they are located.

As you invoked:

```
body = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "p")))
```

Now, `body` contains `List` of *WebElements*. So when you invoked:

```
print(body)
```

The reference of the elements gets printed to the console as follows:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="e7dfa6b2-1ddf-438d-b562-1e2ac8416e07")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="6fe1ffb0-17a8-4b64-9166-691478a0bbd4")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="1f510a00-a587-4ae8-9ecf-dd4c90081a5a")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="c1bfb1cd-5ccf-42b6-ad4c-c1a70486cc98")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="be44db09-3948-48f1-8505-937db509a157")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fb183e8b-ce36-47e7-a03e-d3aeea376304", element="68f3c9f2-80b0-493e-a47f-ad69caceaa06")>]
```

A lot depends on what exactly you are trying to print. As you have decided to collect the elements with `<p>` tag, possibly you may desire to print the text within. In that case you need to `scrollIntoView` the element and then print the **innerHTML** as follows:

```
body = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "p")))
for element in body:
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for node in body: 
    print(node.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

this will print `innerHTML` as a string.

Comment: Note that `body` is actually a `list`. The working code should be `for node in body: print(node.get_attribute('innerHTML')) `